# Custom query on wordpress

Tags: php, content-management-system, posts, wordpress

well I have a wordpress loop in wich I want to query posts from 2 categories, I want to show the common posts between the categories... 
Like if the post "test" belongs to the category "x" and also to the category "y" thats what I want to query.
I've tried something like

```
            <?php query_posts('cat=x&&cat=y'); ?>
```

But this brings the posts from the two categories, not the ones that overlap...
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use this

```
query_posts( array( 'category__and' => array(x,y));
```

Where x and y are the id's of the categories

Answer (score 0):

The cat=267 would be where you select your category, but you have to have a loop to put the posts in the page.

```
<?php query_posts('cat=267') ?>
        <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

            <div id="post" <?php post_class(); ?>>

                <h2 class="entry-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a> <?php edit_post_link( __( 'Edit', 'redlust' ), '<span class="edit-link">', '</span>' ); ?></h2>
                <p class="post-meta">Posted in <?php the_category(', ') ?>, on <?php the_time('F jS, Y'); ?>, by <?php the_author_meta(display_name); ?> <strong>|</strong> <?php comments_popup_link('No Comments &#187;', '1 Comment &#187;', '% Comments &#187;'); ?></p>
                    <div class="entry-content">
                        <?php the_content('Read the rest of this entry &raquo;'); ?>
                        <?php wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<div class="page-link">' . __( 'Pages:', 'redlust' ), 'after' => '</div>' ) ); ?>
                    </div><!-- .entry-content -->
            </div>

        <?php endwhile; ?>
```